# MySQL update values from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

So this is my table structures if it helps:

[image]

```
 UPDATE songs
-> SET artist_id =
-> (SELECT artist_id FROM artists WHERE artists.name = songs.artist);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 27  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

My code keeps matching rows but never ends up changing anything in the actual table

Any ideas on why it's not working?

Comment: The screenshot is good data.  You should have copy-pasted that data as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code basically looks correct.  I would write it as:

```
UPDATE songs s
    SET artist_id = (SELECT a.artist_id 
                     FROM artists a 
                     WHERE a.name = s.artist
                    );
```

If this query returns an error, then `artist_id` is not in `artists`.  You probably want `a.id`.

If this query does not update anything, then the `artist_id`s already have the same value.

Comment: I tried but I just got this error instead: ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'a.artist_id' in 'field list'

Comment: That worked, all I had to do was change my artist_id to artists.id Thanks!

Comment: @coyotecipher . . . That is the first explanation.  Use `a.id` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You may try using an update join here:

```
UPDATE songs s
LEFT JOIN artists a
    ON a.name = s.artist
SET artist_id = a.artist_id;
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff Would a left join handle this edge case?

Answer (score 1):

classic use case for an update join.

```
UPDATE songs
JOIN artists ON song.artist = artist.name
SET songs.artist_id = artists.artist_id;
```

None of these syntaxes, however,  will change the fact that the data is already up to date.

> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
>   Rows matched: 27  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

27 `songs` rows were matched.  The `artist_id` of each was already set to the corresponding `artists.artist_id`.  So O rows were affected or changed.  No warnings were generated.  Just because a query matched rows doesn't mean it changed them.